# How can I make my context menu don't disappear after click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, contextmenu, menuitem

I have a menu that appears when the user clicks on the first row of a table:

```
<menu type="context" id="mnuTitle">
    <menuitem type='checkbox' label='id' checked></menuitem>
    <menuitem type='checkbox' label='name'></menuitem>
</menu>
```

And in the table first row I have

```
<tr contextmenu='mnuTitle'>
```

So far, so good. But when the user clicks on any menu item, the menu disappears (default behavior). How can I force it to don't disappear, using only javascript/html/css?

PS1: I'm using Firefox, and the code only needs to work with Firefox (looks like menu tag only works with Firefox, by now). Thanks!

PS2: Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ffdctn9t/4/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98473/discussion-between-zeke-and-rodrigo).

Comment: Quite right, I missed the tag, the question was still a little hard to decipher, but it's clearer now (especially as I'm paying more attention).

Comment: Thank you. And sorry if the question wasn't clear. English is not my mother tongue.